Clicking button opens page X until after countdown the open page Y
Clicking button opens page X until after countdown the open page Y
I am making this surprise website for my wife, it consists of the index page being a countdown until a certain date. with 1 button that opens the gift. now i want the button to either be locked until the countdown is done, or if possible have it open a page where i tease here like "oh no you dont" but if the timer is at 0 then the actual prize would open. if that makes any sense . either or way of it working would be amazing.
here is my code pen for easier debug and preview: https://codepen.io/Probler/pen/KKLJxqO


const targetDate = new Date('July 15, 2024 00:00:00');

function updateCountdown() {
    const now = new Date();
    const remainingTime = targetDate - now;

    if (remainingTime <= 0) {
        // If the countdown is finished, display all zeros
        document.getElementById('days').textContent = '00';
        document.getElementById('hours').textContent = '00';
        document.getElementById('minutes').textContent = '00';
        document.getElementById('seconds').textContent = '00';
        clearInterval(interval); // Stop the countdown
        return;
    }

    // Calculate the time parts
    const days = Math.floor(remainingTime / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    const hours = Math.floor((remainingTime % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    const minutes = Math.floor((remainingTime % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    const seconds = Math.floor((remainingTime % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    // Display the time parts in the corresponding span elements
    document.getElementById('days').textContent = days.toString().padStart(2, '0');
    document.getElementById('hours').textContent = hours.toString().padStart(2, '0');
    document.getElementById('minutes').textContent = minutes.toString().padStart(2, '0');
    document.getElementById('seconds').textContent = seconds.toString().padStart(2, '0');
}

// Update the countdown every second
const interval = setInterval(updateCountdown, 1000);

// Initial call to display the countdown immediately
updateCountdown();
body {
  background-color: #1e1f22;
}

.download {
  font-family: "JetBrains Mono", monospace;
  background-color: #383c44;
  height: 35px;
  width: 70px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 23px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  color: #4cb1c2;
}

.tab {
  margin: 3rem;
  margin-left: 3.6em;
}

.centered {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  display: block;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

h1 {
  font-family: "JetBrains Mono", monospace;
  font-size: 35px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  line-height: 0%;
  color: white;
}

p {
  font-family: "JetBrains Mono", monospace;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-top: 3px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  color: #abb2bf;
}

.border {
  outline: auto;
  outline-color: #383c44;
  outline-offset: 15px;
  outline-width: 5px;
  outline-style: solid;
  padding: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 1%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 1%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 1%;
  border-top-left-radius: 1%;
}

.window {
  background-color: #383c44;
  height: 35px;
  width: 150px;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  text-align: left;
}

.win-pos {
  transform: translateY(-15px);
}

.dot {
  height: 13px;
  width: 13px;
  background-color: #FF6961;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: translate(126px,-38px);
}
  <body>
    <!--Center Content-->
    <div class="centered">
      <div class="window win-pos">
        <p>Countdown</p>
        <div class="dot">
          </div> 
      </div>
      <div class="border">
        <!--Clock-->
    <h1>
      <span style="color: #c678dd;">Until</span>
      <span style="color: #abb2bf;">Gift</span>
      <span style="color: #4cb1c2;">:</span>
      <span style="color: #ffd700;">{</span>
    </h1>
    <h1 span class="tab">
      <span style="color: #abb2bf;"> &#09;</span>
      <span style="color: #e06c75;">Days</span><span style="color: #4cb1c2;">:</span>
      <span style="color: #d19a66;" id="days"></span><span style="color: #abb2bf;">,</span>
    </h1>
    <h1 span class="tab">
      <span style="color: #abb2bf;">&#09;</span>
      <span style="color: #e06c75;">Hours</span><span style="color: #4cb1c2;">:</span>
      <span style="color: #d19a66;" id="hours"></span><span style="color: #abb2bf;">,</span>
    </h1>
    <h1 span class="tab">
      <span style="color: #abb2bf;">&#09;</span>
      <span style="color: #e06c75;">Minutes</span><span style="color: #4cb1c2;">:</span>
      <span style="color: #d19a66;" id="minutes"></span><span style="color: #abb2bf;">,</span>
    </h1>
    <h1 span class="tab">
      <span style="color: #abb2bf;">&#09;</span>
      <span style="color: #e06c75;">Seconds</span><span style="color: #4cb1c2;">:</span>
      <span style="color: #d19a66;" id="seconds"></span><span style="color: #abb2bf;">,</span>
    </h1>
    
    <h1 span class="tab">
      <span style="color: #abb2bf;">&#09;</span>
      <span style="color: #e06c75;">Unlock Gift</span><span style="color: #4cb1c2;">:</span>

      <span style="color: #ffd700;">
        <button class="download" onclick="window.location.href='special.html'">Open</button>
      </span>

      <span style="color: #68a66b;" id="period"></span><span style="color: #abb2bf;">,</span>
    </h1>

    <h1>
      <span style="color: #ffd700;">}</span><span style="color: #abb2bf;">;</span>
    </h1>
  </div>
</div>



if this isnt the right place to ask then im sorry! but if you could redirect me where i should be that would be helpful.

You should include the minimal relevant code in your question, preferably as a stack snippet. External links can break, which leaves them useless to future readers.

But aside from that, how is your code not working as expected?

What is "until after countdown the open page Y" supposed to mean? Can you rephrase it more clearly?

If I understood correctly what you want. So:
You need first thing to create 2 HTML pages one for surprise. and the second to 'ho no...'
Then change the button to:
<button class="download" onclick="openGift()">Open</button>

and create the function in JS:
 function openGift() {
 if (targetDate <= new Date()) {
 window.location.href = 'gift.html'
 }
 else {
 window.location.href = 'lock.html'
 }
 }

Full code:


  const targetDate = new Date('July 15, 2024 00:00:00');
  function openGift() {
    if (targetDate <= new Date()) {
    alert("gift unlocked");
      window.location.href = 'gift.html'
    }
    else {
        alert("gift lock");
      window.location.href = 'lock.html'
    }
  }
  function updateCountdown() {
    const now = new Date();
    const remainingTime = targetDate - now;

    if (remainingTime <= 0) {
      // If the countdown is finished, display all zeros
      document.getElementById('days').textContent = '00';
      document.getElementById('hours').textContent = '00';
      document.getElementById('minutes').textContent = '00';
      document.getElementById('seconds').textContent = '00';
      clearInterval(interval); // Stop the countdown
      return;
    }

    // Calculate the time parts
    const days = Math.floor(remainingTime / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    const hours = Math.floor((remainingTime % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    const minutes = Math.floor((remainingTime % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    const seconds = Math.floor((remainingTime % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    // Display the time parts in the corresponding span elements
    document.getElementById('days').textContent = days.toString().padStart(2, '0');
    document.getElementById('hours').textContent = hours.toString().padStart(2, '0');
    document.getElementById('minutes').textContent = minutes.toString().padStart(2, '0');
    document.getElementById('seconds').textContent = seconds.toString().padStart(2, '0');
  }

  // Update the countdown every second
  const interval = setInterval(updateCountdown, 1000);

  // Initial call to display the countdown immediately
  updateCountdown();
  body {
    background-color: #1e1f22;
  }

  .download {
    font-family: "JetBrains Mono", monospace;
    background-color: #383c44;
    height: 35px;
    width: 70px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 23px;
    font-weight: bolder;
    color: #4cb1c2;
  }

  .tab {
    margin: 3rem;
    margin-left: 3.6em;
  }

  .centered {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    display: block;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }

  h1 {
    font-family: "JetBrains Mono", monospace;
    font-size: 35px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    line-height: 0%;
    color: white;
  }

  p {
    font-family: "JetBrains Mono", monospace;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    font-weight: bolder;
    color: #abb2bf;
  }

  .border {
    outline: auto;
    outline-color: #383c44;
    outline-offset: 15px;
    outline-width: 5px;
    outline-style: solid;
    padding: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 1%;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 1%;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 1%;
    border-top-left-radius: 1%;
  }

  .window {
    background-color: #383c44;
    height: 35px;
    width: 150px;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    text-align: left;
  }

  .win-pos {
    transform: translateY(-15px);
  }

  .dot {
    height: 13px;
    width: 13px;
    background-color: #FF6961;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transform: translate(126px, -38px);
  }
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
  <!--Center Content-->
  <div class="centered">
    <div class="window win-pos">
      <p>Countdown</p>
      <div class="dot">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="border">
      <!--Clock-->
      <h1>
        <span style="color: #c678dd;">Until</span>
        <span style="color: #abb2bf;">Gift</span>
        <span style="color: #4cb1c2;">:</span>
        <span style="color: #ffd700;">{</span>
      </h1>
      <h1 span class="tab">
        <span style="color: #abb2bf;"> &#09;</span>
        <span style="color: #e06c75;">Days</span><span style="color: #4cb1c2;">:</span>
        <span style="color: #d19a66;" id="days"></span><span style="color: #abb2bf;">,</span>
      </h1>
      <h1 span class="tab">
        <span style="color: #abb2bf;">&#09;</span>
        <span style="color: #e06c75;">Hours</span><span style="color: #4cb1c2;">:</span>
        <span style="color: #d19a66;" id="hours"></span><span style="color: #abb2bf;">,</span>
      </h1>
      <h1 span class="tab">
        <span style="color: #abb2bf;">&#09;</span>
        <span style="color: #e06c75;">Minutes</span><span style="color: #4cb1c2;">:</span>
        <span style="color: #d19a66;" id="minutes"></span><span style="color: #abb2bf;">,</span>
      </h1>
      <h1 span class="tab">
        <span style="color: #abb2bf;">&#09;</span>
        <span style="color: #e06c75;">Seconds</span><span style="color: #4cb1c2;">:</span>
        <span style="color: #d19a66;" id="seconds"></span><span style="color: #abb2bf;">,</span>
      </h1>

      <h1 span class="tab">
        <span style="color: #abb2bf;">&#09;</span>
        <span style="color: #e06c75;">Unlock Gift</span><span style="color: #4cb1c2;">:</span>

        <span style="color: #ffd700;">
          <button class="download" onclick="openGift()">Open</button>
        </span>

        <span style="color: #68a66b;" id="period"></span><span style="color: #abb2bf;">,</span>
      </h1>

      <h1>
        <span style="color: #ffd700;">}</span><span style="color: #abb2bf;">;</span>
      </h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>


</html>




I just needed to perform a little DOM manipulation to add a functional onClick directly when the timer reaches zero.
<span style="color: #ffd700;">
    <button class="download" onclick="window.location.href='special.html'">Open</button>
  </span>

to
<span style="color: #ffd700;">
    <button class="download" id="download">Open</button>
  </span>

and
const remainingTime = targetDate - now;

if (remainingTime <= 0) {
    // If the countdown is finished, display all zeros
    document.getElementById('days').textContent = '00';
    document.getElementById('hours').textContent = '00';
    document.getElementById('minutes').textContent = '00';
    document.getElementById('seconds').textContent = '00';
    clearInterval(interval); // Stop the countdown
    return;
}

to
const remainingTime = targetDate - now;
let button = document.getElementById("download");

if (remainingTime <= 0) {
    // If the countdown is finished, display all zeros
    document.getElementById('days').textContent = '00';
    document.getElementById('hours').textContent = '00';
    document.getElementById('minutes').textContent = '00';
    document.getElementById('seconds').textContent = '00';
    clearInterval(interval); // Stop the countdown
    button.onclick = function() {
      window.location.href = 'https://www.google.com.br';
    };
    return;
}


@KevinB its genuinely not me, not even sure who this person is. i did however post the solution i ended going with below. i cant accept it for another 18 hours though.

Have a hidden button that goes to the new page and then when the countdown is finished, hide the first button and reveal the hidden button. In the example below the Open button will open a page at https://example.com. There's also a new button added for demonstration purposes labeled T-minus Zero. Click that button to simulate the end of the countdown. At the end of the countdown the Open button's text should be yellow and when clicked it should open to the new page which is https://stackoverflow.com.
Details are commented in the example below.


let targetDate = new Date('July 15, 2024 00:00:00');

function updateCountdown() {
  const now = new Date();
  const remainingTime = targetDate - now;

  if (remainingTime <= 0) {
    // If the countdown is finished, display all zeros
    document.getElementById('days').textContent = '00';
    document.getElementById('hours').textContent = '00';
    document.getElementById('minutes').textContent = '00';
    document.getElementById('seconds').textContent = '00';
    clearInterval(interval); // Stop the countdown

    // Hide the first button and reveal the second button
    document.getElementById('close').classList.add("hidden");
    document.getElementById('open').classList.remove("hidden");
    return;
  }

  // Calculate the time parts
  const days = Math.floor(remainingTime / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  const hours = Math.floor((remainingTime % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  const minutes = Math.floor((remainingTime % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  const seconds = Math.floor((remainingTime % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  // Display the time parts in the corresponding span elements
  document.getElementById('days').textContent = days.toString().padStart(2, '0');
  document.getElementById('hours').textContent = hours.toString().padStart(2, '0');
  document.getElementById('minutes').textContent = minutes.toString().padStart(2, '0');
  document.getElementById('seconds').textContent = seconds.toString().padStart(2, '0');
}

// Update the countdown every second
const interval = setInterval(updateCountdown, 1000);

// Initial call to display the countdown immediately
updateCountdown();

// For demonstration purposes only
document.getElementById('zero').onclick = function() {
  targetDate = new Date();
};
/* ⸸ A change for aesthetics */

body {
  background-color: #1e1f22;
}

button {
  font-family: "JetBrains Mono", monospace;
  background-color: #383c44;
  padding: 2px 8px;  /* ⸸ */
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 23px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  color: #4cb1c2;
  cursor: pointer;  /* ⸸ */
}

#open {
  color: gold;  /* ⸸ */
}

/* This class selector hides the button it's assigned to */
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.tab {
  margin: 3rem;
  margin-left: 3.6em;
}

.centered {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

h1 {
  font-family: "JetBrains Mono", monospace;
  font-size: 35px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  line-height: 0%;
  color: white;
}

p {
  font-family: "JetBrains Mono", monospace;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-top: 3px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  color: #abb2bf;
}

.border {
  outline: auto;
  outline-color: #383c44;
  outline-offset: 15px;
  outline-width: 5px;
  outline-style: solid;
  padding: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 1%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 1%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 1%;
  border-top-left-radius: 1%;
}

.window {
  background-color: #383c44;
  height: 35px;
  width: 150px;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  text-align: left;
}

.win-pos {
  transform: translateY(-15px);
}

.dot {
  height: 13px;
  width: 13px;
  background-color: #FF6961;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: translate(126px, -38px);
}

/* For demonstration purposes only */
.test {
  position: absolute;
  top: 18%;
  left: 80%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
<body>
  <!--Center Content-->
  <div class="centered">
    <div class="window win-pos">
      <p>Countdown</p>
      <div class="dot">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="border">
      <!--Clock-->
      <h1>
        <span style="color: #c678dd;">Until</span>
        <span style="color: #abb2bf;">Gift</span>
        <span style="color: #4cb1c2;">:</span>
        <span style="color: #ffd700;">{</span>
      </h1>
      <h1 span class="tab">
        <span style="color: #abb2bf;"> &#09;</span>
        <span style="color: #e06c75;">Days</span><span style="color: #4cb1c2;">:</span>
        <span style="color: #d19a66;" id="days"></span><span style="color: #abb2bf;">,</span>
      </h1>
      <h1 span class="tab">
        <span style="color: #abb2bf;">&#09;</span>
        <span style="color: #e06c75;">Hours</span><span style="color: #4cb1c2;">:</span>
        <span style="color: #d19a66;" id="hours"></span><span style="color: #abb2bf;">,</span>
      </h1>
      <h1 span class="tab">
        <span style="color: #abb2bf;">&#09;</span>
        <span style="color: #e06c75;">Minutes</span><span style="color: #4cb1c2;">:</span>
        <span style="color: #d19a66;" id="minutes"></span><span style="color: #abb2bf;">,</span>
      </h1>
      <h1 span class="tab">
        <span style="color: #abb2bf;">&#09;</span>
        <span style="color: #e06c75;">Seconds</span><span style="color: #4cb1c2;">:</span>
        <span style="color: #d19a66;" id="seconds"></span><span style="color: #abb2bf;">,</span>
      </h1>

      <h1 span class="tab">
        <span style="color: #abb2bf;">&#09;</span>
        <span style="color: #e06c75;">Unlock Gift</span><span style="color: #4cb1c2;">:</span>

        <!--
            This button will open the "oh no you dont" page (in
            this example it is: https:example.com).
            Once the countdown is finished, it will be assigned
            the ".hidden" class.
        -->
        <span style="color: #ffd700;">
        <button id="close" onclick="window.location.href='https://example.com'">Open</button>
        <!--
            This button is hidden and opens the "Gift" page (in
            this example it is: https://stackoverflow.com).
            Once the countdown is finished, the class ".hidden"
            is removed.
        -->
        <button id="open" class="hidden" onclick="window.location.href='https://stackoverflow.com'">Open</button>
      </span>

        <span style="color: #68a66b;" id="period"></span><span style="color: #abb2bf;">,</span>
      </h1>

      <h1>
        <span style="color: #ffd700;">}</span><span style="color: #abb2bf;">;</span>
      </h1>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- 
      This is only for demonstration purposes.
  -->
  <section class="test">
    <div class="window win-pos">
      <p>Test</p>
      <div class="dot">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="border">
      <button id="zero">T-minus Zero</button>
    </div>
  </section>




People here posted answers that I'm SURE will work but I ended up finding a better implementation that I ended up using.
i added an event listner in my java script:
function handleButton() {
    if (remainingTime > 0) {
        // Go to no prize page
        window.location.href = '/Images/fakeloading.html';
    } else {
        // Go to prize page
        window.location.href = '/Images/special.html';
    }
}

// Add event listener to the button once the DOM content is fully loaded
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const downloadbtn = document.getElementById('downloadbtn');
    downloadbtn.addEventListener('click', handleButton);
});

and this is what i did with the HTML side.
<span><button id="downloadbtn" class="open">Open</button></span>

this event listner will check the timer, if its above 0 it opens the fake webpage. but when its 0 itll open the real one.
